# Java, how to inherit methods from abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract

I have an abstract class Person and and interface comparable, which is also used for some other part of the program. Currently I have a method compareTo() in Person. When I try to compile, I get :

```
The type Student must implement the inherited abstract method 
 Comparable<Person>.compareTo(Person, Person)
```

What exactly do I have to do? I don't wont to implement this method in any of the subclasses, because I need this method for all of them, Student, Tutor, Professor, etc... Is there a better way of doing this?

Interface:

```
interface Comparable<Element> {
    public int compareTo(Element nodeA, Element nodeB);
}
```

Abstract class Person:

```
abstract class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    protected String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person personB) {
        int comp = this.name.compareTo(personB.getName());
        return comp;
    }
}
```

And class Student

```
class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private int id;

    public Student(String name, int id) {
        super(name);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int newID) {
        id = newID;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + ", " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your interface from:

```
interface Comparable<Element> 
{     
   public int compareTo(Element nodeA, Element nodeB); 
}
```

to:

```
interface Comparable<Element> 
{     
   public int compareTo(Element nodeA); 
}
```

And make your Person class be defined as:

```
abstract class Person implements Comparable<? extends Person> { /* ... */ }
```

And make your Student (and other Person-subclasses be):

```
class Student extends Person { /* ... */ }
```

That is all.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Comparable<Element>` class declares a method `public int compareTo(Element nodeA, Element nodeB);`, but in your `Person` class, you implement `public int compareTo(Person personB)`, which is not the same method signature.

You need to either implement `public int compareTo(Person personA, Person personB)`, or alter your `Comparable<Element>` class's method definition to be `public int compareTo(Element other);` to override the core `Comparable` class's [compareTo method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Also, as @murat mentions below in the comment, using the `@Override` annotation would help you out (assuming you're on Java version 1.5 or higher).  If you add `@Override` to a method that you're not actually overriding from a superclass (such as your two-argument `compareTo` method), then it will be a compiler error.

Comment: This is probably the most complete correct answer. Moreover, it is good to add @Override tag before the methods you override to make sure they match with some method in the superclass or interface.

Comment: Comment by user without comment privileges ([Hound Dog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1068649/hound-dog)): If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse, you can easily generate methods from an interface or abstract class (using `Source->Override/Implement Methods` in Eclipse) and prevent defining new methods that don't have the same signature.

Answer (score 2):

Your Comparable interface has a method `compareTo(Element nodeA, Element nodeB)`. This method is not defined in Student, and it's not defined in Person either. Person has the following method:

```
public int compareTo(Person personB)
```

, which doesn't override `compareTo(Person nodeA, Person nodeB)`

Why are you redefining the standard `java.util.Comparable` interface?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the method as it appears in the interface, i.e. with two arguments

```
public int compareTo(Person nodeA, Person nodeB)
```

To avoid such problems in the future use the `@Override` annotation:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person nodeA, Person nodeB)
```

This will cause a compilation error if you try to override a method, but make a mistake in its signature.

Also, consider using Java's standard [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
public int compareTo(Person nodeA, Person nodeB)
```

In your `Person` class. Currently you only have:

```
public int compareTo(Person personB)
```

Comment: He's defining his own Comparable interface, see the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry removed my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a compareTo method in the Student class.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Comparable<Element> {
    public int compareTo(Element nodeA, Element nodeB);
}
```

It makes sense if it was either:

```
interface Comparator<Element> { //comparator compares two instances of same type
    public int compare(Element nodeA, Element nodeB);
}
```

or (has to be something like this for your case):

```
interface Comparable<Element> { //comparable compares itself with another instance of same type
    public int compareTo(Element that);
}
```

But for both cases, you should use the standard Java interfaces: Even though you are only using [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) also see [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).